# New key word in abstract class declaration C#

Tags: c#, class, abstract

Does anybody know what is "new" keyword mean in this code?

```
 public abstract class RepositoryBaseSingle<T,D> where T :class where D : DataContext, new()
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class
>   declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the
>   new constraint, the type cannot be abstract. Apply the new constraint
>   to a type parameter when your generic class creates new instances of
>   the type, as shown in the following example:

```
class ItemFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```